# Insert/Add new entity with nested children entities to DB using Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Here are Entities:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }

}

public class EntityBase : Entity
{
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
    public int? ModifiedById { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }

}

public class ProjectRequest : EntityBase
{
    public string RequestTitle { get; set; }
    public string RequestType { get; set; }
    ...
   
    public virtual ICollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class Material : EntityBase
{
    [ForeignKey("ProjectRequest")]
    public int ProjectRequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectRequest ProjectRequest { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Translation> Translations { get; set; }
}

public class Translation:EntityBase
{
    [ForeignKey("ProjectRequest")]
    public int ProjectRequestId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProjectRequest ProjectRequest { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Material")]
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
    public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
    public string ProductMasterText { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(40)]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
    public string MasterDescriptionLine1 { get; set; }
    public string MasterDescriptionLine2 { get; set; }
    public string MasterDescriptionLine3 { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
}
```

No modifications has been done to these entities using fluent API.
Now, whenever I try to insert object of type **ProjectRequest** with **Materials** and **Translations** nested in it, in *Translation* objects ProjectRequestId is set to 0.

Following is sample Change Tracker snapshot:

[image]

Can anyone help me on this? Why ProjectRequestId is 0 but MaterialId properly assigned in Transaltion objects?

Comment: Can you see if `Id` is in fact the primary key in the database? If not, add `[Key]` above the `public int Id {get;set;}` line.

Comment: @klekmek it is primary key